# Git how to prevent load some changes

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, sourcetree

Is there any tool that can help me prevent error with changing base urls. Sometimes I need to test production url instead of development url sometimes. I have two different paths for the same baseURL variable. But what I want is prevent to upload this changes to github. How can I select some snippet of text to just prevent this changes to be commuted. So actually before commit this changes I need to rollback baseUrl to previous state. So I know for sure I can track it manually and see if I still have another url string, but maybe we can add some thing at start that will notify me that I will need to change that url before committing.

Comment: Not entirely clear on what you're trying to achieve, but I think you might be able to codify the logic inside a pre-commit git hook

Comment: @JeffPuckettII thanks for comment! after I modified some line I want to hook up it and after I will try to commit then I want source tree or terminal to say me that I have a line of code that I don't want to be committed.